# Creating a single link for spatially separated words in sentence

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Let's say I have a sentence with a number of words and I want to create a link from more than one word in this sentence that are not next to each other, so that when hovering over one of the words, the hover effect will also be applied to the other words that are linked to the same address.

Example:
I have a [link]dog[/link] called [link]fluffy[/link].

The words "dog" and "Fluffy" would be linked to the exact same page, and if hovering over "dog", "Fluffy" would also be highlighted.

Can I in some way accomplish this using only HTML (and CSS)? If not, a solution with (preferably pure) JavaScript is fine too. I want a solution that works even if I have several different kinds of paired links (although they don't necessarily have to be pairs) within one sentence, and even if I have hundreds of sentences with this kind of linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/JhjuT/

```
Grumpy <a class="link" href="#">wizards</a> make toxic brew for the evil <a class="link" href="#">Queen</a> and Jack.

$(".link").hover(
    function () {
        $(".link").addClass("linkhover");
    },
    function () {
        $(".link").removeClass("linkhover");
    }
);

.linkhover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I'm first and foremost looking for a pure JavaScript solution. Could it be done along the same lines?

Comment: Yeah, you could use a pure JavaScript solution I'm sure. I'm not very good at JavaSCript so I was happy when jQuery came along as it let me do lots of things that I previously pulled my hair out over.

Comment: I might go over to the jQuery camp eventually too, but I'll wait until I have experienced first-hand the reasons why it makes things better :) At the moment I'm working on quite small project, so I'll try to stay with the bare minimum of technologies. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think the javascript solution is your best bet.  You can almost do it with CSS.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.sentence:hover .word {background-color:red;}
</style>
<body>
<span class=sentence>I have a <span class=word>dog</span> called <span class=word>fluffy</span>.</span>
</body>
</html>
```

But in this case the style is applied to both words when you hover anywhere over the sentence.

Comment: Each other word will have different links, so it won't quite do it. Thanks anyway!